# Current line highlighting in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I modified color scheme of editor to use darker colors, but there is no current line highlighting option. So I can't remove bright white highlighting of the current line.

Is there a way to disable highlighting of the current line or to change its color?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Syntax highlighting. In the list of all the highlighting options, scroll almost to the bottom, to the end of the **Line highlighting** part. There you will find *current*, where you can define the colouring for the current line. The middle colour is the background colour.

[image]

#### Old answer, which probably applied to an older version of TeXstudio

Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Editor. In the list of all the highlighting options, scroll almost to the bottom, to the end of the **Line highlighting** part. There you will find *current*, which defines the background colour of the current line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted! Sorry, I thought that if colors are not defined, they should be transparent, so I haven't even tried to change these values.

Comment: This modifies the color of the highlighted line.
But what about the current paragraph? Even if you don't select anything the paragraph where the cursor is changes its color to grey.  And it could be quite a little bit annoying.  How can I disable it?

Comment: @skan I don't think there is a "paragraph concept" in this context. But if you write a lot of text without adding line breaks, and line wrapping is enabled, what is actually a single line in the file, is displayed across multiple lines in the editor. If line numbering is enabled you can probably see that the same line number applies to your entire "paragraph".  I guess adding line breaks in the code is the best fix. Can't see an option for doing what you ask, but you could add a feature request at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who can´t find that setting under "Editor":
See this little checkbox on the bottom left saying "Show Advanced Options"?
Click it and go to the new point "Syntax Highlighting", scroll down to "Line highlighting" and here you go :)