# Restoring default color scheme of TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

After getting help from her: [Current line highlighting in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85038/current-line-highlighting-in-texstudio) to change the color scheme of the texstudio editor, I ran into a problem:

Those features not marked with color as default, are actually transparent. Once you select a color for that feature, i.e. the text background (which is different from the editor background), I can not get it back to the default transparent setting.

What I did:

In order to figure out how the color scheme for highlighting works, I tried to set the originally white `background` to 'red'. Afterwards I set the color for `background` back to 'white', which apparently worked fine. Except now highlighting the `current line` only works for the part not filled with text.

The default setting of 'white' turned out to rather be 'nothing': it is actually coded as 'black', i.e. all 0s and with the `color name` `#000000`.

I suppose that if I restore the default settings of TexStudio, all settings including compiler and bibliographic tool etc. will be restored too.

Hence the question, is there a way to restore (only) the color scheme of TexStudio?

Comment: Search your `texstudio.ini` file for `Color\\` and remove the entries you don't like. See https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored for the location of the file.

Comment: @ samcarter, You are my hero. Thanks. I want to credit you for giving me a solution. Can I do that  now or must you create a 'real' answer?

Comment: Actually I didn't change anything, I just deleted the .ini file - which was then recreated with default settings

Comment: Wrote a short answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the colours individually by **right-clicking** on the colour box. (i.e., for "no colour"). If you want to "restore to default" colouring scheme, @samcarter's answer is the way to go.

[image]

Comment: While samcarter's advise helped me solve my problem, I must admit that this would have been quite easier. Thanks for the advise which I will remember. I can only mark one answer as the one solving my problem - otherwise I would have also marked this one.

Comment: @jbahn Please feel free to accept this answer - it seems much easier.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. I just wanted to commend you for your efforts. I'll be looking for another chance for that.

Answer (score 4):

All your custom settings are stored in the `texstudio.ini` file (see https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored  for the location).

- If you want to undo your colour settings search this file for `Color\` and remove the colours you don't like
- or delete the entire file if you want to undo all your settings